# ERROR POST http://localhost:8088/geolib/libros 400

Tags: angular

necesito ayuda por favor, estoy realizando un post de un formulario de libros y al momento de guardarlos y enviarlos a la lista me sale este error POST http://localhost:8088/geolib/libros 400, ademas de este

core.mjs:6494 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8088/geolib/libros', ok: false, …}

y no entiendo el por que para el front estoy utilizando angular y para el back spring boot

spring boot

@RestController

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")

@RequestMapping(path = "/geolib/libros")

public class LibroController {

```
@Autowired
private LibroServiceImpl libroServiceImpl;

@GetMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(){
    try{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(libroServiceImpl.findAll());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("{\"error\":\"Error. Por favor intente mas tarde.\"}");
    }
}

@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Libro entity){
    try{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(libroServiceImpl.save(entity));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("{\"error\":\"Error. Por favor intente mas tarde.\"}");
    }
}
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Libro entity){
    try{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(libroServiceImpl.update(id, entity));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("{\"error\":\"Error. Por favor intente mas tarde.\"}");
    }
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable String id){
    try{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(libroServiceImpl.delete(id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("{\"error\":\"Error. Por favor intente mas tarde.\"}");
    }
}
```

Consola Spring Boot

```
           2022-06-28 11:34:16.137  WARN 30204 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved    [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type`java.util.ArrayList<com.lib.api.entities.Autor>` from Object value(token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type`java.util.ArrayList<com.lib.api.entities.Autor>` from Object value(token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)<EOL> at [Source:(org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain:com.lib.api.entities.Libro["autores"])]
```

clase libro.ts

```
   import { Autor } from "./autor";
   import { Cuenta } from "./cuenta";
  import { Editorial } from "./editorial";
  import { Genero } from "./genero";

 export class Libro {
      constructor(){
         this.autores=new Autor();
        this.generos=new Genero();
        this.editoriales=new Editorial();
        this.cuenta=new Cuenta();
      }

  isbn!: string;
  titulo!:string;
  descripcion!:string;
  stock!:string;
  precioUnitario!:number;
  fechaRegistro!:Date;
  autores!:Autor;
  generos!:Genero;
  editoriales!:Editorial;
  cuenta!:Cuenta;
 }
```

LIBRO.SERVICE

```
   export class LibroService {

   libro!:Libro;
    private url:string="http://localhost:8088/geolib/libros";

   constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

 getAllL():Observable<Libro[]>{
   return this.http.get<Libro[]>(this.url)};

  /////crear libro///POST

       createLi(libros:Libro):Observable<Libro>{
         return this.http.post<Libro>(this.url,libros)
          }
```

///obtener 1 libro

```
  get(isbn:Libro):Observable<Libro>{
    return this.http.get<Libro>(this.url+'/id/'+isbn);
 }
```

///actualizar

```
   update(libros:Libro):Observable<Libro>{
     return this.http.put<Libro>(this.url+'/',libros);
    }
```

///eliminar

```
    delete(isbn:string):Observable<Libro>{
      return this.http.delete<Libro>(this.url+'/'+isbn);
    }
```

lIBROFORM. COMPONENT

```
 export class LibroformComponent implements OnInit {
  libro:Libro=new Libro();
  constructor(private libroservice:LibroService, private fb:FormBuilder, private 
  router:Router) {
```

}

```
 ngOnInit() {

   }

   create():void{
    console.log(this.libro);
    this.libroservice.createLi(this.libro).subscribe
    (resp=>this.router.navigate(['/lista']));
    }
```

HTML

```
     <form>

          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <label class="form-label" for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
              <textarea class="form-control"  id="descripcion" rows="4" 
               [(ngModel)]="libro.descripcion" name="descripcion"></textarea>
              </div>   
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
       (click)="create()">Guardar</button>

  </form>
```

en consola.log si se me muestran los datos, pero cuando ya quiero guardarlos y mandarlos a la lista con el post es lo que aparece este problema, alguien que me quiera ayudar por favor muchas gracias

Comment: Si quieres que te podamos ayudar, lo que necesitamos es saber qué pone en la consola del backend, no un mensaje de error genérico que esté devolviendo... eso no da nada de información. De hecho, eso no sirve para nada en realidad a la hora de programar. Lo que te interesa es el error que haya dado en el backend, no el que se presenta al usuario. Mira en donde ejecutas el servicio de spring, que tienes que tener un stacktrace diciéndote exactamente qué error es.

Comment: WARN 30204 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.lib.api.entities.Autor>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Comment: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.lib.api.entities.Autor>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.lib.api.entities.Libro["autores"])]

Comment: si, esto es lo q me sale en la conosla de spring boot

Comment: Parece que espera que autores sea un array list y le estás enviando uno solo? Aunque solo sea uno, debes enviarlo como lista. Haría falta ver el payload que estás enviando para verlo más claro. Y por cierto, la información se añade a través del botón [edit] directamente en la pregunta, no en comentarios por favor.

Comment: ok, como recien estoy empezando no me percate,  ya modifique la información y gracias por responder, ya le voy a revisar esa parte de mi codigo